# How to save output result of hg commands in a file?

Tags: mercurial

I am trying to save output of Mercurial commands in a file

```
hg init > log.txt
```

but its not working. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure the output is not simply silent by default?

`hg init`, for instance, rarely (if ever?) actually prints any output.  Many Mercurial commands are the same way.  You can often specify `-v` to get more verbose output, but in the case of the example you gave, I would expect an empty `log.txt` to appear.  Have you tried other commands?  If so, what exactly is not working?  Do you get an empty `log.txt` or no `log.txt` at all?

Comment: I get an empty file. If hg init throws an error like "repository already exist", I want to check that error in my script. Is that possible ?

Comment: Let me elaborate more on this..

I am trying to automate hg commands using firefox extension. I am using process.run to execute these commands. Sometimes when you update your repository, you get conflicts error in command prompt. I want to check if there any conflicts exist, give user option to discard or merge.

Does that make sense ?

Comment: @Nitesh: yes, it's possible.  In this case I think Borealid's answer is correct, you need to check the output on standard error in addition to standard out.  Some *nix shells and Windows may require the redirection in the reverse order though, e.g. `hg init >log.txt 2>&1` (the `2>&1` tells the shell to redirect anything written to stderr over to stdout).

Comment: Thanks for the info...Can you store standard output value in a variable in Javascript instead of writing in to a file and then reading it ?

Answer (score 3):

The output might be on standard error.

Try `hg init 2>&1 > log.txt`.

**Note**: As [bjlaub noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3190699/how-to-save-output-result-of-hg-commands-in-a-file#comment3298124_3190834) you might have to reverse the order to `hg init > log.txt 2>&1` on Windows.

Comment: This is the actual answer (as suggested by bjlaub, but hidden in the comments of the accepted answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with hg log. With special templates the output on console worked, but when I tried to redirect into a file, no file was created.

I used the following workaround (for windows cmd):
In the batch file, use a subroutine, like shown below:

```
call :hgInit > log.txt
goto :eof

:hgInit
hg init
goto :eof
```

That worked for me.